# Kubernate Pod : How to import Certificate into Java Truststore?

Tags: java, docker, security, kubernetes

So in my environment i am using Docker and Kubernete ,now i have to import a certificate in Pods Java Keystore .
But my Container running as a `NON-ROOT` user .When i am trying to import the certificate to Java Keystore its failing as to accessing Java Keystore user have to be root user only.

```
keytool -importcert -alias keycloakTest -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -file $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/keycloak.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

Now How i can import the certificate into Java trust store? Currently i am doing this manually but later i have to do this through `DockerFile`

```
COPY /carFiles/keycloak.crt  $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/
CMD keytool -importcert -alias keycloakTest -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -file $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/keycloak.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

In Kubernete Pods Java run as a `root` user only?

Edit

I made changes in Docker File something like this

```
COPY /carFiles/keycloak.crt /opt
CMD keytool -importcert -alias keycloakTest -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -file /opt/keycloak.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

So from Pods Shell i am able to see certificate Copied to `/opt` directory but next `CMD` command wont able to add the certificate into the truststore of java

[image]

Enter key or you will be logged out any time after 101 min.

```
spec:
      volumes:
        - name: certs
          emptyDir: {}
      initContainers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-create-keystore-truststore
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 100
          image: >-
            <HOST>/foapi-tools:20.0.1

 command:
            - sh
            - '-c'
            - >
             # Import Keycloak server certificate into truststore

              # Extract host name from ckey URL

              KEYCLOAK_HOST=$(echo
              "https://<HOST>/auth" | sed
              's|[^/]*//\([^/]*\)/.*|\1|')

              echo "Importing server cert of '${KEYCLOAK_HOST}'..."

              openssl s_client -connect ${KEYCLOAK_HOST}:443 2>/dev/null
              </dev/null | openssl x509 > keycloak.crt

              ls -lat /certs/truststore;
          workingDir: /certs/truststore
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 200m
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 200m
              memory: 100Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: certs
              mountPath: /certs/truststore
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Comment: As per my understanding, you are getting the public cert of the Keycloak during the container initialization and trying to add it to the `cacerts` of the Java. If you want to access the `/opt` path, the user who is performing the Keytool command requires the Sudo permissions.

Comment: But in WSO2 a user will be there which will be not a root user.

Comment: May I know, which WSO2 Product your using and why you are trying to import the Keycloak cert to the `cacerts` (without in-cooperating WSO2 keystore)?

Comment: I am using `/wso2/wso2mi:4.0.0` so our product build on top of WSO2,so we will update some jar and car file after downloading the WSO2 image then recreated the image .Now from this modified product we call SOAP API which will take keycloak token when we will run our API.

Comment: So, you can import the certs to the MI's Keystores. There is no need to add the cert directly to the `cacerts`. Do you have any special requirements as such to put the certs into `cacerts` (would like to understand a little more)?

Comment: Generally whenever a application want to connect to over https with another application or in my case Keycloak we have to import the certificate into the client machine from where code is running so i was following same concept here as well. Whats this MI' Keystore we have to import certificate in java keystore right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If the WSO2 MI is the only application is going to perform the communication from the container, then you can import the Keycloak's cert to the MI's `client-truststore.jks` directly. Follow these [1](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/security/using_keystores/#understanding-keystores-and-truststores) [2](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/setup/security/importing_ssl_certificate/#importing-ssl-certificates-to-a-truststore) for more information.

Comment: So MI keystore wont need root permission to import the certificate like in the case of java keystore of container?

Comment: Correct. You don't need root permissions to import the certs to the MI's Keystore and Trust-stores. We can take this to a discussion for better understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234360/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-athiththan).

Answer (score 1):

As per the shared information, you are using WSO2 MI and trying to generate a token from the Mediation sequence with Keycloak. In such a case, it is not required to add the Keycloak's cert to the `cacerts` of the JDK. You can make use of the WSO2 MI's `client-truststore.jks` to import the certs.

To access the `/opt` path, the user needs root permission. As WSO2 MI itself contains a truststore and not requires any root permissions to import the certs, you can simply import the Keycloak's TLS public cert in there. Given is a sample `Dockerfile` to import the certs

```
COPY /carFiles/keycloak.crt $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/resources/security/
RUN keytool -importcert -alias keycloakTest -keystore $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks -file $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/resources/security/keycloak.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

> Note: Replace the `CMD` with the `RUN` command, as you are trying to import the certs to the truststore as part of building the images. And not setting that command as an entrypoint to start the containers.

Further, if you have a certifier chain, you have to include all (root, intermediate, and leaf certs) in the truststore. Importing only one of them will result again in an SSL Handshake error.

Comment: Failing with error `keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
The command '/bin/sh -c keytool -importcert -alias keycloakTesting -keystore $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks -file $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/resources/security/keycloak.cer -storepass changeit -noprompt' returned a non-zero code: 1
`

Comment: The Keystore password you have entered is wrong. In the command, you have used `changeit` as the password. You have to change that to the actual password of the Keystore and try again

Comment: but its a default password for Mi keystore.

Comment: ok password in this case is `wso2carbon`.

Comment: Yes, the default password for `client-truststore.jks` is `wso2carbon`.

Answer (score 0):

This is up to your container, or more specifically the file permissions on the jks file. That file is part of your image and is presumably owned by uid 0 and mode 660 or something, so would need to change something for this to work. Either do this at build time or change ownership/mode of the file or use a different jks file.

Comment: Do you mean this should be done in `DockerFile` or `deployment.yaml`. In this file i have to add the user or file permission if yes how?

Comment: Generally in the Dockerfile. But you can do this purely at runtime by asking cert-manager to generate things in a JKS format (or using an init container to convert things) and using the `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/your.jks` system parameter.

Comment: Please have a look edited question,i am downloading certificate from another server in init container only,Let me add that also in the question